# AMCharts Map not rendering in production mode

Tags: angular, amcharts

I developed an Angular application with AMCharts Map.

- In development mode (ng serve) I view the map correctly.
- Building the app without production mode (command: ng build) I view the map correctly.
- Building the app with production mode (command: ng build --prod) the map is not rendered. I have no errors in browser console.

It seems that the minimized code doesn't render the map.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.4.8",
    "@amcharts/amcharts4-geodata": "^4.1.5",
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.15",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  }
```

Comment: refresh the page.

Comment: I tried many time, not working!

Comment: Found the solution in the AmCharts documentation:

"Edit the package.json and add --prod --build-optimizer=false to the "build" script:"

Comment: Related: https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/1146

Comment: The same issue occurs when using amcharts in a react application.
Using version 4.7.5

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a late answer but it may help. I'll just copy and paste what I mentioned on the [issue referred by Kavinda](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/1146).

We recently faced this issue (still an issue). As the officially recommended solution is not an option, because our app size is already too large we solved it by [lazy loading amcharts](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/lazy-loading-amcharts-modules/) **AND** explicitly separating amchart scripts using [webpack magic comments](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments). Not exactly what we use but. it may give you an idea:

```
  import(/* webpackChunkName: "amcharts" */ "@amcharts/amcharts4/core"),
  import(/* webpackChunkName: "amcharts" */ "@amcharts/amcharts4/charts"),
  import(/* webpackChunkName: "amcharts" */ "@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/animated")
]).then((modules) => {
  const am4core = modules[0];
  const am4charts = modules[1];
  const am4themes_animated = modules[2].default;

  // Chart code goes here
}).catch((e) => {
  console.error("Error when creating chart", e);
})
```

This will generate a separate chunk called `amcharts.js`

For a detailed explanation read [this article on Angular: Dynamically immporting large libraries](https://medium.com/lacolaco-blog/angular-dynamic-importing-large-libraries-8ec079603d0)

Comment: Hey @JsantaCL. Cool way. Does this works without build-optmizer=false?

Comment: It does, our app is too large so it requires the optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is (according to amCharts), the angular build optimizer remove amChart library and some other libraries when using build optimizer. I know it's kind of confusing. But read this [issue](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/1146). You'll understand why and few workaround to use